# Word for someone who changes hobbies constantly

Tags: word-request

I have a friend who seems to adopt new hobbies on a weekly basis. As in, "I would really like to get in to knife throwing, let me buy a knife for that," and then abandons the idea a week later. There is no particular theme to these hobbies: it can be anything from card counting to hatchet throwing.
Words like "indecisive" don't seem to fit exactly, because he is very decisive once he sets his mind on something. He is not incapable of making a decision; he is incapable of sticking to a decision.

Is there a word to describe someone like this?

Comment: Serial hobbyist

Comment: You could call their latest interest the "flavor of the week" as a cheeky way to poke fun at your friend :) It indicates that they have a new hobby at least once a week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fickle** describes someone who frequently changes their mind.  It can be applied to one's interests.

From [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/fickle):

> Changing frequently, especially as regards one's loyalties or affections.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for "inconsistent".

As mentioned in the [dictionary](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/inconsistent), the meaning of "inconsistent" is:

> 3. not [consistent](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/consistent) in principles, conduct, etc.:
>     He's so inconsistent we never know if he'll be kind or cruel.

And the meaning of "consistent" is:

> 2. constantly adhering to the same principles, course, form, etc.:
>     a consistent opponent.